# Close Print Modal/Print Preview fires onclick

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing

I have a "heavy" html5 webapp, that allows users to print content. When user click my print button, I generate some iframe, populate that with content and then invoke the javascript print() method. Everything works fine.

But, if the user chose to cancel printing on the print-preview/print modal in Chrome, an click event/mousedown event is sent to my app right after the modal is closed.

Any way to prevent this behavior, is it a bug in Chrome?

I am currently using Chrome 38.0.2125.111 in OSX

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a click event to the cancel button and use `preventDefault`. Here's an example with jquery.

```
$('.cancel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you can only use javascript just use `onclick` and do the same thing.

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Close</button>

function myFunction(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();    
}
```

Comment: It is Chrome's own print-preview modal window that is being clicked, I cant do preventDefault on chrome's own UI?

Comment: Is there anyway to extend the modal and then you can add this code? I've never used Chrome's print-preview modal before so I'm not sure.